# Creating com library with starting from empty project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com

.
  I found sample called "Creating a COM Server Using a Text Editor" in MSDN.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wad1c0e(v=vs.71).aspx

It compiles fine from command promt, but not from Visual Studio IDE.

I decided to move this project to Visual Studio. 
  I have created new project (File>>New>>Project>>Empty project) and add MyServer.cpp file to "Source Files" and MyIncludes.h to Header Files. I got following error after I tried to build project:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Myserver, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>MyServer.cpp
1>.\MyServer.cpp(26) : warning C4581: deprecated behavior: '"apartment"' replaced with 'apartment' to process attribute
1>Linking...
1>   Creating library C:\Myserver\Release\Myserver.lib and object C:\Myserver\Release\Myserver.exp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Myserver\Myserver\Release\BuildLog.htm"
1>Myserver - 1 error(s), 1 warning(s)
 ========= Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation errors told you need a entry function in an EXE module.
you must define a **main(...)** function as the entry, otherwise is an invalid EXE since there is no startup point.
Simply, you can create an console window project for IDE, or just add **main(...)** manually as I said.